# Operation 'EmailToApexHandler' is not appearing in debug logs while verifying Email Service

Tags: apex-email-service, debug

Earlier, I have successfully performed the steps outlined in the answer of [how-to-leverage-org-wide-email-address-within-an-email-service](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/221656) to verify the Email Service Address generated by Salesforce.

I'm trying to verify an Email Service in a different sandbox and I don't see the `EmailToApexHandler` operation in the debug logs after I create a new Org Wide Email address. The context user is my user and debug log is also enabled.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have figured out the issue, 'Accept Email From' was populated with Sys Admin's email. Thus the Email Service address wasn't accepting emails from Salesforce.
I made 'Accept Email From' setting as blank and I could see the verification link on the developer console.

[image: Email Service Address Setting]