# Verfication Email link from 'EmailToApexHandler' doesn't work

Tags: apex-email-service, org-wide-email, verification

I have followed the steps outlined in the answer of [how-to-leverage-org-wide-email-address-within-an-email-service](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/221656/how-to-leverage-org-wide-email-address-within-an-email-service) to verify the Email Service Address generated by Salesforce.

I'm attempting to verify the link from the logs, but it doesn't appear to be working. I tried clicking the link or pasting it into the browser, but it just takes me to a Salesforce screen and doesn't verify the org-wide email address.

Comment: did you try pasting into an incognito window?

Comment: Yes, I tried. Nothing works

Comment: you may need to use [edit] and include screen shots of every step along the way; I know I've used the technique in the linked answer in OP before and it has worked for me